# What JSON do I send when I POST using the JIRA REST API?

Tags: json, post, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using **[/rest/api/2/screens/{screenId}/tabs/{tabId}/fields](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e1492)** to POST fields into a tab in JIRA but I can't figure out how the JSON that I'm POSTing should be structured.

I'm receiving this error message, which is extremely difficult to understand (and Google has been minimal help): *`string(298) "{"errorMessages":["Unrecognized field \"id\" (Class com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.AddFieldBean), not marked as ignorable\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5383f8a; line: 1, column: 8] (through reference chain: com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.AddFieldBean[\"id\"])"]}"`*

Here's the JSON that I'm currently sending: *`'{"id":"customfield_11930","name":"1st Review Ready"}';`*

Comment: For future reference, including your POST content would make it much easier for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct JSON structure: {"fieldId":"id"}